# Node.js & redis / zadd objects to a set

Tags: node.js, redis

I have the following code:

```
var db = require("redis");
var dbclient1 = db.createClient();

dbclient1.zadd("myprivateset", 3, {"guid":"abab-baba", "data-persistent":"xxxx", "size":"20"})
dbclient1.zadd("myprivateset", 2, {"guid":"abab-baba3", "data-persistent":"xxxx", "size":"20"})
dbclient1.zrangebyscore("myprivateset", 1, 4)
dbclient1.hgetall("myprivateset", function(err, rep){
 console.log(rep);
});
```

I wish to store my objects (in JSON format) in a sorted set, which determine by the score (3 & 2 in our case).

For some reason, when I print this table (`rep`), I get undefined.

What I do wrong?

Comment: Node.js is async. You can't write something to DB and then immediately read it.

Answer (score 6):

**Issue 1 -- sorted set keys**

Try stringifying the JSON you are using as the keys of your sorted set. For example,

```
dbclient1.zadd("myprivateset", 3, {"guid":"abab-baba", "data-persistent":"xxxx", "size":"20"})
```

needs to be:

```
dbclient1.zadd("myprivateset", 3, JSON.stringify({"guid":"abab-baba", "data-persistent":"xxxx", "size":"20"}))
```

Without stringifying the keys, every zadd will use the key `[object Object]` overwriting each time.  That is, you'll only ever have one item in your sorted set that is unidentifiable (other than by `[object Object]`).

**Issue 2 -- fetching data**

Also, `hgetall` is not the redis command to use for retrieving data in a redis sorted set.  You'll want to focus on sorted set specific commands.  A list of redis commands are listed here: http://redis.io/commands

Comment: It still prints undefined

Comment: I don't think hgetall is what you want.

Comment: // returns all in score range from 1-4
`dbclient1.zrangebyscore("myprivateset", 1, 4, function(err, rep) {
 console.log(rep);
});`

// returns paginated from 0 to 5
`dbclient1.zrevrange("myprivateset", 0, 5, function(err, rep) {
 console.log(rep);
});`

Comment: HGETALL is for hashes, and you're using a sorted set so you'll want to use sorted set retrieval methods instead of hash ones to access the data. (http://redis.io/commands)

Answer (score 4):

Seems like with Redis 6.2 the format has changed to and object with `score` and `value` attributes or an array of those, like this:

```js
async function sortedSet() {
  let client;
  try {
    client = createClient();

    client.on("error", (err) => console.log("Redis Client Error", err));

    await client.connect();
    console.log("connected");

    await client.zAdd("user:0:followers", [{score: "1", value: "John"}, {score: "2", value: "Other John"}]);
    console.log("sorted set added");

  } finally {
    await client.quit();
  }
}

sortedSet("duto_guerra", "with hashes");
```

In case you are wondering, I figured this out by reading the source code for [node-redis ZADD](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/packages/client/lib/commands/ZADD.ts)

Comment: thanks. i was getting super frustrated and the docs don't mention sorted sets specifically, that it is zAdd (not zadd), or this new format.

Comment: Thank you for this. Had no idea that we had to use a list of score and value pairs. Really got me frustrated.

Answer (score 3):

My two cents, building on comments by @leonid-beschastny and @cpentra1. I recommend using `redis.multi()`. It allows for several calls in a batch, and as you can see in the example, as soon as the three elements are added to the ordered set, we can perform a `zrangebyscore` in the same `multi` batch and get the expected results. Instructions can be created dynamically. The `replies` array when `multi.exec()` is invoked returns the results for each of the `multi` operations, in order.

```
var db = require("redis");
var dbclient1 = db.createClient();
var multi = dbclient1.multi();

// We use JSON.stringify() as suggested by @cpentra1 
multi.zadd("myprivateset", 3, JSON.stringify({"guid":"abab-baba", "data-persistent":"xxxx", "size":"20"}));
multi.zadd("myprivateset", 2, JSON.stringify({"guid":"abab-baba3", "data-persistent":"xxxx", "size":"20"}));
multi.zadd("myprivateset", 2, JSON.stringify({"guid":"abab-dafa3", "data-persistent":"yyyy", "size":"21"}));
multi.zrangebyscore("myprivateset", 1, 4);
multi.zcard("myprivateset"); // The total number of elements in the set
multi.exec(function(err, replies) {
    console.log(replies)
    // Will output something like:
    // [ 1,
    //   1,
    //   1,
    //   [ '{"guid":"abab-baba3","data-persistent":"xxxx","size":"20"}',
    //     '{"guid":"abab-dafa3","data-persistent":"yyyy","size":"21"}',
    //     '{"guid":"abab-baba","data-persistent":"xxxx","size":"20"}' ],
    //   3 ]
});
```

Note: if you run the same example twice, instead of `1`s in the first three elements of the `replies` array, you'll get `0`s as the same member with the same score cannot be added twice.